# Is uid mandatory for devise token auth to find current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, devise-token-auth

With default configuration of devise token auth, `uid` is identical to user’s email and is mandatory to find current user. But my requirement is that i need to hide `uid` in http header when request and response due to security risk. Is this possible?

Comment: The only time the client sends its credentials are when they are trading them for a token. In that case they are sent in the body of the post request. I don't see how placing the credentials in a header makes any kind of difference when it comes to man in the middle attacks.

Comment: But this is requirement. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, you could use [Warden Basic Auth](https://github.com/opf/warden-basic_auth) or write your own Warden strategy. However you will need to learn a bit about how Warden works and its role in Devise.